# Retrofit- Trouble with json parsing using Gson

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson

I am new to Retrofit. I've used volley for most Web-Services, decide to move on Retrofit. But I'm stuck on Json parsing, I'm getting empty data in my POJO class.
I tried to check response by `Call<ResponseBoby>` my response was correct by when I use to parse in my model class I'm getting blank data. Please Guide me, Any help would be appreciated.

Note: POJO class is parcelable and also contains cunstructor and gette/setter. I removed it from here cause of text limit.

> CODE

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(PRODUCT_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    ApiInterface apiService = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    JsonObject ob = new JsonObject();
    ob.addProperty("pro_id", model.getId());
    Call<Product> call = apiService.getProducts(ob);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Product>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Product> call, Response<Product> response) {
            Product p = response.body();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.body().getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Product> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("ERROR",call.toString());
        }
    });
```

> API INTERFACE

```
public interface ApiInterface {
     @POST("app/product.php")
     Call<Product> getProducts(@Body JsonObject jsonObject);
}
```

> POJO Class

```
public class Product {

@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
public String title;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
public int id;
@SerializedName("created_at")
@Expose
public String createdAt;
@SerializedName("updated_at")
@Expose
public String updatedAt;
@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
public String type;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
public String status;
@SerializedName("downloadable")
@Expose
public boolean downloadable;
@SerializedName("virtual")
@Expose
public boolean virtual;
@SerializedName("permalink")
@Expose
public String permalink;
@SerializedName("sku")
@Expose
public String sku;
@SerializedName("price")
@Expose
public String price;
@SerializedName("regular_price")
@Expose
public String regularPrice;
@SerializedName("sale_price")
@Expose
public Object salePrice;
@SerializedName("price_html")
@Expose
public String priceHtml;
@SerializedName("taxable")
@Expose
public boolean taxable;
@SerializedName("tax_status")
@Expose
public String taxStatus;
@SerializedName("tax_class")
@Expose
public String taxClass;
@SerializedName("managing_stock")
@Expose
public boolean managingStock;
@SerializedName("stock_quantity")
@Expose
public int stockQuantity;
@SerializedName("in_stock")
@Expose
public boolean inStock;
@SerializedName("backorders_allowed")
@Expose
public boolean backordersAllowed;
@SerializedName("backordered")
@Expose
public boolean backordered;
@SerializedName("sold_individually")
@Expose
public boolean soldIndividually;
@SerializedName("purchaseable")
@Expose
public boolean purchaseable;
@SerializedName("featured")
@Expose
public boolean featured;
@SerializedName("visible")
@Expose
public boolean visible;
@SerializedName("catalog_visibility")
@Expose
public String catalogVisibility;
@SerializedName("on_sale")
@Expose
public boolean onSale;
@SerializedName("product_url")
@Expose
public String productUrl;
@SerializedName("button_text")
@Expose
public String buttonText;
@SerializedName("weight")
@Expose
public Object weight;
@SerializedName("dimensions")
@Expose
public Dimensions dimensions;
@SerializedName("shipping_required")
@Expose
public boolean shippingRequired;
@SerializedName("shipping_taxable")
@Expose
public boolean shippingTaxable;
@SerializedName("shipping_class")
@Expose
public String shippingClass;
@SerializedName("shipping_class_id")
@Expose
public Object shippingClassId;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
public String description;
@SerializedName("short_description")
@Expose
public String shortDescription;
@SerializedName("reviews_allowed")
@Expose
public boolean reviewsAllowed;
@SerializedName("average_rating")
@Expose
public String averageRating;
@SerializedName("rating_count")
@Expose
public int ratingCount;
@SerializedName("related_ids")
@Expose
public List<Integer> relatedIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
@SerializedName("upsell_ids")
@Expose
public List<Object> upsellIds = new ArrayList<Object>();
@SerializedName("cross_sell_ids")
@Expose
public List<Integer> crossSellIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
@SerializedName("parent_id")
@Expose
public int parentId;
@SerializedName("categories")
@Expose
public List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
@SerializedName("tags")
@Expose
public List<Object> tags = new ArrayList<Object>();
@SerializedName("images")
@Expose
public List<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();
@SerializedName("featured_src")
@Expose
public String featuredSrc;
@SerializedName("attributes")
@Expose
public List<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
@SerializedName("downloads")
@Expose
public List<Object> downloads = new ArrayList<Object>();
@SerializedName("download_limit")
@Expose
public int downloadLimit;
@SerializedName("download_expiry")
@Expose
public int downloadExpiry;
@SerializedName("download_type")
@Expose
public String downloadType;
@SerializedName("purchase_note")
@Expose
public String purchaseNote;
@SerializedName("total_sales")
@Expose
public int totalSales;
@SerializedName("variations")
@Expose
public List<Variation> variations = new ArrayList<Variation>();
@SerializedName("parent")
@Expose
public List<Object> parent = new ArrayList<Object>();

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
}
```

> JSON Response

```
{
  "product": {
    "title": "Flying Ninja",
    "id": 70,
    "created_at": "2013-06-07T11:25:01Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-09-26T05:55:35Z",
    "type": "simple",
    "status": "publish",
    "downloadable": false,
    "virtual": false,
    "permalink": "http:\/\/codiixx.com\/product\/flying-ninja\/",
    "sku": "",
    "price": "12.00",
    "regular_price": "15.00",
    "sale_price": "12.00",
    "price_html": "<del><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&#36;<\/span>15.00<\/span><\/del> <ins><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">&#36;<\/span>12.00<\/span><\/ins>",
    "taxable": true,
    "tax_status": "taxable",
    "tax_class": "",
    "managing_stock": false,
    "stock_quantity": null,
    "in_stock": true,
    "backorders_allowed": false,
    "backordered": false,
    "sold_individually": false,
    "purchaseable": true,
    "featured": false,
    "visible": true,
    "catalog_visibility": "visible",
    "on_sale": true,
    "product_url": "",
    "button_text": "",
    "weight": null,
    "dimensions": {
      "length": "",
      "width": "",
      "height": "",
      "unit": "cm"
    },
    "shipping_required": true,
    "shipping_taxable": true,
    "shipping_class": "",
    "shipping_class_id": null,
    "description": "<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.<\/p>\n",
    "short_description": "<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.<\/p>\n",
    "reviews_allowed": true,
    "average_rating": "4.00",
    "rating_count": 4,
    "related_ids": [
      76,
      79,
      73,
      67
    ],
    "upsell_ids": [

    ],
    "cross_sell_ids": [

    ],
    "parent_id": 0,
    "categories": [
      "Posters"
    ],
    "tags": [

    ],
    "images": [
      {
        "id": 71,
        "created_at": "2013-06-07T11:24:19Z",
        "updated_at": "2013-06-07T11:24:19Z",
        "src": "http:\/\/codiixx.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/poster_2_up.jpg",
        "title": "poster_2_up",
        "alt": "",
        "position": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 72,
        "created_at": "2013-06-07T11:24:47Z",
        "updated_at": "2013-06-07T11:24:47Z",
        "src": "http:\/\/codiixx.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/Poster_2_flat.jpg",
        "title": "Poster_2_flat",
        "alt": "",
        "position": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 10260,
        "created_at": "2017-07-10T06:51:22Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-07-10T06:51:22Z",
        "src": "http:\/\/codiixx.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/images.jpeg",
        "title": "images",
        "alt": "",
        "position": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 10261,
        "created_at": "2017-07-10T06:52:18Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-07-10T06:52:18Z",
        "src": "http:\/\/codiixx.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/Jazbaa-Movie-Full-Audio-Album-Free-Download-Mp3-Song-2015.jpg",
        "title": "Jazbaa-Movie-Full-Audio-Album-Free-Download-Mp3-Song-2015",
        "alt": "",
        "position": 3
      },
      {
        "id": 10264,
        "created_at": "2017-07-10T09:34:49Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-07-10T09:34:49Z",
        "src": "http:\/\/codiixx.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/07\/entrepreneur-593371_640.jpg",
        "title": "entrepreneur-593371_640",
        "alt": "",
        "position": 4
      },
      {
        "id": 10234,
        "created_at": "2017-04-06T06:01:10Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-04-06T06:01:10Z",
        "src": "http:\/\/codiixx.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/04\/img1.jpg",
        "title": "img1",
        "alt": "",
        "position": 5
      },
      {
        "id": 469,
        "created_at": "2016-11-04T06:26:58Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-04-06T05:03:30Z",
        "src": "http:\/\/codiixx.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/11\/test1-1.jpg",
        "title": "test1",
        "alt": "",
        "position": 6
      },
      {
        "id": 10215,
        "created_at": "2017-03-28T06:17:00Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-04-06T05:03:29Z",
        "src": "http:\/\/codiixx.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/03\/download.jpg",
        "title": "download",
        "alt": "",
        "position": 7
      },
      {
        "id": 327,
        "created_at": "2016-06-24T10:42:33Z",
        "updated_at": "2016-06-24T10:42:33Z",
        "src": "http:\/\/codiixx.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/06\/logo-phoeniixx.jpg",
        "title": "logo-phoeniixx",
        "alt": "",
        "position": 8
      },
      {
        "id": 98,
        "created_at": "2013-06-07T11:37:17Z",
        "updated_at": "2013-06-07T11:37:17Z",
        "src": "http:\/\/codiixx.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/cd_5_flat.jpg",
        "title": "cd_5_flat",
        "alt": "",
        "position": 9
      }
    ],
    "featured_src": "http:\/\/codiixx.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/poster_2_up.jpg",
    "attributes": [

    ],
    "downloads": [

    ],
    "download_limit": -1,
    "download_expiry": -1,
    "download_type": "standard",
    "purchase_note": "",
    "total_sales": 91,
    "variations": [

    ],
    "parent": [

    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: i think your pojo class is wrong kindly create and check pojo class from this link http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: @Lingeshwaran i created from there

Comment: Did you try to print your response? Is it coming right?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh i create and checked its show different from your class

Comment: finally got it to work.. thanks all guyz helping me

Answer (score 1):

Though you are sending json data to the URL using the json object the main purpose is to get the data so the annotation should be get instead of post

```
public interface ApiInterface {
     @GET("app/product.php")
     Call<Product> getProducts(@Body JsonObject jsonObject);
}
```

Comment: by using post im getting this error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-body HTTP method cannot contain @Body`

Comment: what are you trying to do?I guess you want to get data while you also need to post some data to server to get that?right?

Comment: If that is the case you should use GET and not POST

Comment: You want to post id?then what is that response?

Comment: response contains total information of product as shown in json

Comment: Abhishek usually in get request with body the Url query is recommmend..You are sending just an ID..so instead of body it is better to make it path or query

Comment: bro i'm getting response correctly... data parsing error.. i checked using Call<ResponseBody> for raw data response

Answer (score 1):

You'r exposing your fields.

Aslong as you dont revert the exposing using GSON-Settings all `@EXPOSE`'d annoated fields will be ignored for serialize and deserialize. You dont need do use serialized name annotation if the name matches your var (take care about proguard)

```
public class Product implements Parcelable{
private String title;
private int id;
private String created_at;
private String updated_at;
private String type;
// ....
}
```

You can revert that using [excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation--)

Another reason may be, that you'r POSTing data to your webserver. Aslong as the response of your webserver to your POST isnt the data above, you wont get anything. Did you mean `@GET()`?

Also validate if you get only 1 Product as repsonse. Getting multiple results should be `Call<List<Product>>` in your Retrofit Service.

Comment: by using post im getting this error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-body HTTP method cannot contain @Body`

Comment: Yes, because GET() doesnt allow Body annotation to send data. Keep your POST and rework your webserver to accept post and return the proper data.

Comment: my webservice accepts post data.. getting response in `volley` also by `Call<ResponseBody>`

Comment: As written above. remove the expose or create a proper GSON Builder to revert the expose annotation

Comment: so I need to remove `@Expose1 annotation.? and how to create GSON Builder can you show me by code using by one or two variable in model class

Comment: Yes. But you shouldnt copy/paste, you need to understand. expose means "remove something". It allows you to define if serialize AND deserialize or you can use EXPOSE(serialize=...,deserialize=...)

Comment: But please give me a demo code so that i can understand more. I'm noob to gson library.. I parsed this json manually but it takes lots of time so I'm trying gson.. but not understanding how to create model class for gson. I genrated this class from jsonscema2pojo. i've a differece in this class and my model class there were two annotation added more only.. I don't understand its m,eaning

Answer (score 1):

```
JsonObject ob = new JsonObject();
ob.addProperty("pro_id", model.getId());
```

instead of sending a json object, make a model class that you will send. See the below implementation for model class i.e DTO:

PropertyDTO.java

```
public class PropertyDTO {
    @SerialisedName("pro_id")
    @Expose
    private String proId;

    public String getProId(){
        return proId;
    }

    public void setProId(String s) {
        this.proId = s;
    }
}
```

Change the API Interface like this :

```
public interface ApiInterface {
     @POST("app/product.php")
     Call<Product> productsAPI(@Body PropertyDTO ob);
}
```

Now for the response class i.e Product, copy the entire json data and paste it in http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and in the options select target language: java, source type: json, annotation style: gson and tick the following checkboxes:

```
"Use primitive types"
"Use double numbers"
"Allow additional properties"
```

Now in android studio generate the constructor or setters and getters. That's it. For further help you can see the following tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8SYedH6wC8&list=PLCBuiMPCrrW1BDDxd91tCW1OMzCRzMvjX

Use Stetho Network Interceptor in order to know whats going on while you do a network call. For Stetho see this link.

https://github.com/facebook/stetho

your Retrofit instance will have a minor change :

```
OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor());

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(PRODUCT_URL)
            .client(okHttpBuilder.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Remember to initialise your Stetho in your onCreate method and use a singleton class instead of creating retrofit instances in different activities. Follow this link for more info:

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client

Comment: problem is not in sending data.. problem i in parsing data

Comment: did you try parsing the json reponse in http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to get the classes